# How to convert binary data by using linked server to DB2/AS400 in SQL Server 2012?

Tags: sql-server, database, db2, oledb, db2-400

We have two database servers, the both of them using SQL Server 2012, but the OS is different. The older one is using Windows Server 2008R2 Standard, while the newer one is Windows Server 2012R2 Standard, both of them is x64. The other difference is the *exact* version number of the SQL Server, so the older is

- Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 11.0.3128.0
- Microsoft Data Access Components (MDAC) 6.1.7601.17514
- Operating System  6.1.7601

while the newer:

- Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 11.0.5343.0
- Microsoft Data Access Components (MDAC) 6.3.9600.17415
- Operating System 6.3.9600

I already created a properly working linked server to get data from our DB2/AS400 database on the old server. I used Data Access Tool 4.0 to make a connection string and got the following one:

```
Provider=DB2OLEDB;User ID=****;Initial Catalog=CAT;Network Transport Library=TCPIP;Host CCSID=37;PC Code Page=1252;Network Address=****;Network Port=446;Package Collection=DATA;Default Schema=DATA;Process Binary as Character=True;Units of Work=RUW;Default Qualifier=DATA;DBMS Platform=DB2/AS400;Use Early Metadata=False;Defer Prepare=False;DateTime As Char=False;Rowset Cache Size=0;Binary CodePage=0;Datetime As Date=False;AutoCommit=True;Database Name=TEST_DB;Authentication=Server;Decimal As Numeric=False;Derive Parameters=False;LoadBalancing=False;Persist Security Info=False;Cache Authentication=False;Connection Pooling=False;
```

Nowadays I would like to make the same linked server on the new one, but it couldn't convert the binary data as a proper one.

For example data from old server compared to the new one:

1. "" === 0x404040
2. M === 0xD4

Connection string that used on the new server:

```
Provider=DB2OLEDB;User ID=****;Initial Catalog=CAT;Network Transport Library=TCPIP;Host CCSID=37;PC Code Page=1252;Network Address=****;Network Port=446;Package Collection=DATA;Default Schema=DATA;Process Binary as Character=True;Units of Work=RUW;Default Qualifier=DATA;DBMS Platform=DB2/AS400;Use Early Metadata=False;Defer Prepare=False;DateTime As Char=False;Rowset Cache Size=0;Binary CodePage=0;Datetime As Date=False;AutoCommit=True;Database Name=TEST_DB;Authentication=Server;Decimal As Numeric=False;Derive Parameters=False;LoadBalancing=False;Persist Security Info=False;Cache Authentication=False;Connection Pooling=False;
```

I already tried:

- Used Data Access Tool 4.0 because it already worked in the past (Process Binary as Character = True)
- Used Data Access Tool 5.0 to be more compatible with SQL Server 2012 (Process Binary option is not included)
- Installed hotfix from the MS Support (https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2993741)
- Went through the possible settings and tried some combinations
- Compared the already working linked server and the newly created one

Please help me how can I solve this problem!

Comment: What versions of actual SQL *Server* are the servers running? (Use `SELECT @@VERSION` on each server to find out. The version of the management studio isn't relevant; you can connect to SQL Server 2005 using SQL Server Management Studio 2014, for example.)

Comment: The old one:
Microsoft SQL Server 2012 (SP1) - 11.0.3128.0 (X64) 
Dec 28 2012 20:23:12 
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation
Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.1 <X64> (Build 7601: Service Pack 1)

New one:
Microsoft SQL Server 2012 - 11.0.5343.0 (X64) 
May  4 2015 19:11:32 
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation
Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.3 <X64> (Build 9600: ) (Hypervisor)

Answer (score 0):

Installed the i series ODBC driver on to the system and configured a system DSN, which should connect to the database.

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/eae2d05f-32e8-4541-87fb-70fc12697d15/ms-ole-db-provider-for-db2-v5?forum=sqldataaccess